# Permission Error [Errno 13] Permission denied: while running python script in windows

Tags: python-3.x

I want to access my hosts file...
but i am getting permission error even though i logged in my admin privilege..

here is the error message,

```
Permission Error [Errno 13] Permission denied:C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

[image: Permission Error [Errno 13] Permission denied]

Answer (score 1):

Try cmd.exe with administrator permission by **right click** on `cmd.exe` 
and choose **run as administrator**

otherwise, right click on folder (in your case its `hosts` path)

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

in this folder, choose properties-> find permission give read write access..